# How to render a byte array from socket/application using DirectShow?

Tags: directshow

I have an application. I will have a situation, wherein I will receive a big array of encoded bytes. I have to decode them and render it. For decoding, I am using a custom decoder class. After the decode, how can I construct a DirectShow graph which will receive input data from the decoder? Please give some direction/samples on this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the PushSource sample in the DirectShow SDK. This sample shows you how to create a source filter that can be rendered. It is all about setting the output media type of your filter correctly so that the rest of the graph can be rendered.  The sample also shows you how to feed media samples to the rest of the media pipeline. In your case what do you decode to? The PushSource sample outputs RGB24 IIRC.

Also, it sounds like you're decoding in the same filter as your receiving the bytes in? Typically in DirectShow you would write a source filter that is able to receive bytes from the network and outputs samples in the encoded format. You would then connect this filter to a custom decoder filter, that then outputs either RGB24 or some raw media format that is understood by DirectShow. Similarly for audio, you could output say, PCM.

Edit:
I have used the same approach (CSource, CSourceStream). That is correct, the DoBufferProcessingLoop calls FillBuffer. My general approach has been to use the producer-consumer pattern. The networking-reading thread populates the queue with samples and in my overridden DoBufferProcessingLoop I check whether the queue has any data, calling FillBuffer if there is data. You can of course try other methods such as waiting on events (frame availibility). To see the approach I used you can download the source code of an example RTSP source filter at http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/ and see if that suits you. Best thing I would say is to just try stuff and learn as you go along.

Comment: My question was regarding the second thread of my application, which will keep waiting for incoming H 264 encoded byte array. It will decode the received byte arrays to say YV12/I420 using the decoder routine. This decoder is not a filter as such. What I am planning is, the decoding byte array will be given to the Source Filter (to be created as in PushSource, what you have suggested). Please validate this idea.

Comment: You can of course do it that way. My comment was intended to highlight other approaches, which is useful to componentise/modularise the software. E.G we use our H.264 encoders/decoders in multiple scenarios/applications and having the two actions "receive from network" and "decode" in separate filters allows us to reuse the filters. In the end however whatever works for you is what counts. As long as your media type is set correctly, you will be able to render the graph.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the hint. I have a few questions after going through the sample once.
This is a DLL. How will I register this so that I can use it from GraphEdt or from DirectShow Application programming context? 

Any usage example of this is most welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Shiju

Comment: You register it like any DirectShow filter using the regsvr32 <<filename>> from a command window. Once registered successfully, the filter will be listed in the DirectShow category in graphedit.

Comment: Could you please look at the "Answer" that I typed and get back? Using the "Add Comment" option, I am not able to type my full text.